# How to check is string contains any of special characters?

Tags: java

I want to check is some string contains ANY special symbol from UNICODE charset or not. Previosly I harcoded it with regular expression charset, but now list of chars expanded and its not an option to hardcode it now. How to set this check?

Comment: Define "special symbol". Is 串 a special symbol?

Comment: Any unicode special characters, for example https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html

Comment: Doesn't answer my question. Is Ä a special character or just an A with an umlaut? Isㅣa special character or just a Korean i?

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through your string and for every character call, then

```
public static boolean checkingUnicode(String text){

        char[] arr = text.toCharArray();

        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            char c = arr[i];
            if(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) != Character.UnicodeBlock.BASIC_LATIN){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

There is an option using Regex.

If it matches regex `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` then there is not special characters in it.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher("I am a string");
boolean containsSpecialChar = m.find();
if(containsSpecialChar){
// Do what you need.
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

I think it can be achieve. You need to make a possible list of special characters defined and apply condition in `loop` for check every character in list for containing that special character.

Answer (score -1):

use the method called Regex.

```
                String s= e2.getText().toString();
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{11}"); //CHANGE PATTERN CONDITIONS ACCORDINGLY
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s); //CHECKS THE PATTERN WITH THE INPUT STRING

                if (matcher.matches()) {
                   // YOUR METHODS 
                }
                else
                {
                    //PRINT AN ERROR TEXT
                }
```